# hbase GREATER_OR_EQAUL operator does not work as expected

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, hbase, apache-phoenix

i have this row in my hbase table:
{rowkey:1_1611646861574/cf:value/1611646776287/Put/vlen=8/seqid=0}
now i want to do a simple scan and find rows where their column value is greater than "1611388300000". but it does not return any record; however it returns this record when i use LESS_OR_EQUAL than 1611647500000.
the weird thing is i can get this record from apache phoenix sql query: select * from my_table where value>=1611388300000.

so number is a obviously bigger than column value and apache phoenix returns it; why hbase compare Operator does not?

here is my code:

```
Table table = con.getTable(TableName.valueOf("my_table"));
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("value"));
FilterList flist = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
flist.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("1")));
flist.addFilter(new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                        Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("value"), CompareOperator.GREATER_OR_EQUAL,
                        new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1611388300000"))));
scan.setFilter(flist);
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next())
     System.out.println("Found row : " + result);
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont exactly know why but LESS_OR_EQUAL works with string:

```
new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                    Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("value"), CompareOperator.LESS_OR_EQUAL,
                    new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1611647500000")))
```

but GREATER_OR_EQUAL did not work when i used quotes so i had to use number (L is added to specify Long)

```
new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                        Bytes.toBytes("ui"), Bytes.toBytes("C"), CompareOperator.GREATER_OR_EQUAL,
                        new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(1611388300000L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're comparing long, you should use LongComparator instead of BinaryComparator:
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/LongComparator.html